# enum as TypeName for ObjectDataSource

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to use an enum as a TypeName for an objectDataSource control:
aspx:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSourceAccessType" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAccessTypes" 
    TypeName="Permission.AccessTypeEnum">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

C#:

```
public class Permission
{
    public enum AccessTypeEnum
    {
        ReadOnly = 0,
        ReadAndSIUD = 1,
        ReadAndRun = 2,
        ReadAndPrint = 3,
        ReadSIUDAndRun = 4,
        ReadSIUDAndPrint = 5,
        ReadSIUDRunAndPrint = 6,
        ReadRunAndPrint = 7,
    }
    public static string[] GetAccessTypes()
    {
        return Enum.GetNames(typeof(AccessTypeEnum));
    }
}
```

but I am getting error:

> The type specified in the TypeName property of ObjectDataSource 'ObjectDataSourceAccessType' could not be found"

what is the wrong I am doing?

Comment: Isn't there a typo in your class name? `Permissiony`?

Comment: sorry I correct it to Permission but this was not the problem

Comment: Did you use the correct namespace too?

Comment: yes but i but her short

Comment: Do you need `TypeName="Permission.AccessTypeEnum"`? I guess your type is is `string`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I am searching internet now someone saying that enum can not used with ObjectDataSource

Comment: TypeName is must what can I put instead

Answer (score 0):

after so many tries I found the solution but I can not understand why?
It works fine after changing TypeName="Permission.AccessTypeEnum" to  TypeName="Permission" in the ObjectDataSource control

Comment: in the type name you should provide a class name not the enum name

Comment: Yes I think this was my problem Thank You